Как получить реферальную ссылку, по которой юзер подписался на канал?
Как реализовать реф ссылку на бота понимаю, там нужно черрез CommandStart вытаскивать.
Мне нужно получать ссылку, по которой юзер подписался на канал.
@router.message(Command('ref'))
async def mt_referal_menu (message: Message):
    link = await bot.create_chat_invite_link(chat_id="@channel")
    await message.answer(str(link))

@router.chat_member(ChatMemberUpdatedFilter(IS_NOT_MEMBER >> IS_MEMBER))
async def process_start_command(message: Message):
    print("Пользователь подписался на канал!")

Во втором роутере как-то нужно вытащить ссылку из этого ивента, если кто-то знает что тут добавить или вообще через другие методы делать, буду благодарен любой помощи, спасибо!
